# Unable to connect to MongoDB Atlas using Vert.x MongoClient

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, vert.x, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect to a MongoDB database hosted in MongoDB Atlas using [Vert.x MongoClient](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mongo-client/java/):

I'm creating MongoClient with this code (Kotlin):

```
MongoClient.create(vertx, jsonObjectOf(
  "connection_string" to "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster_address>/my_db"
))
```

(with real values, obviously)

But I'm unable to perform any operation agains database. I get a connection timeout error:

> com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while
> waiting for a server that matches
> ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of
> cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET,
> servers=[{address=<server1_address>, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING},
> {address=<server2_address>, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING},
> {address=<server3_address>, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]

If I try to connect using `mongosh` (CLI tool) and MongoDB Compass using the same connection string, it works fine.

I have tried confguring the client with parameters (hosts, ports, etc...) instead of using a connection string and I get this error when I make a query:

> MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 11 days struggling with this, I have just solved it.

I have included `"trustAll" : true` option when creating `MongoClient` and it's working now. It's not the best solution, but anyway...